# How to create a Centos Xen domU on Debian Squeeze using xen-create-image

Tags: centos, xen, debian-squeeze

I have a Xen host system based on Debian Squeeze, and installed xen-tools. I would like to setup a CentOS domU using `xen-create-image`. xen-tools already 'knows' of CentOS-5, but I cannot seem to get `xen-create-image` working correctly. I have trouble finding out the necessary parameters I need to pass to `xen-create-image` (especially mirror?). And, of course, it would be nicer to use CentOS-6.

So, how do I create a CentOS-6 (or 5) domU on a Debian Squeeze dom0 (both x86_64), preferably using `xen-create-image`?

Comment: You could try rinse (rinse - RPM installation environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took a while to trudge through and shouldn't die in my notes. This is for Debian 6/Squeeze, xen4 on amd64 hardware.

1. Edit `/etc/rinse/centos-5.packages` and add the following items (probably alpha sorted, but I haven't played around with this):

   - `authconfig`
   - `chkconfig`
   - `libuser`
   - `passwd`
   - `python-libs`
2. Create the base image: `xen-create-image --hostname=foo.example.com --ip=1.2.3.4 --gateway=1.2.3.1 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --install-method=rinse --dist=centos-5 --mirror=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/ --arch=i386`

   - The `---arch=i386` is required, `x86_64` is a non-starter for some reason.
   - Passing `--install-method=rinse` is required.
   - I'm not sure that the `--mirror` flag is required.
3. Create a temp dir to mount the image: `mkdir -m 0700 /tmp/img_mnt`
4. Mount the image: `mount -o loop /home/xen/images/domains/foo.example.com/disk.img /tmp/img_mnt`
5. `chroot`(1) to the new jail: `chroot /tmp/img_mnt /bin/bash`
6. Enable/disable services:

   1. `chkconfig iscsi off`
   2. `chkconfig iscsid off`
   3. `chkconfig rsyslogd on` - Recommended for debugging
7. Setup/convert to shadow passwords: `pwconv`
8. Change the root password: `passwd root`
9. Exit the `chroot`(1)`ed environment: `exit`
10. `unmount`(1) the loopback image: `umount /tmp/img_tmp`
11. Start the VM: `xm create -c foo.example.com.cfg`
12. Login.

Comment: for Debian you use need to use arch=amd64 not arch=x86_64 even if your deploying a centos domU.